# Обмен данными через заголовки

Tags: ajax

На сайте в форме поиска реализую такую "фишку":

```
function GetCountMatch(str){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
}
...
<input type="text" onChange="GetCountMatch(this.value)" />
```

Т.е. серверу нужно отправлять небольшую строку, и получать ответ от сервера в виде числового значения.

Т.е. это происходит в событии `onChange`, то важно быстродействие обмена данными между клиентом и сервером.

Я где то в сети читал, что в таких случаях, когда нужно небольшими данными с сервером обмениваться, то лучше через заголовки их передавать (так быстрее).

Может кто то подскажет как их через заголовок отправлять и как принимать значения на сервере?

Мне кажется, нужно как то так?:

```
function GetCountMatch(str){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("POST", "main.php", true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.setRequestHeader("MyHeader", str);
    x.onreadystatechange = function (){...}
    x.send(null);
}
```

Если - да, то как на сервере принимать этот заголовок?

Answer (score 1):

Если backend это PHP, то стоит попробовать так

```
$_SERVER['MyHeader']
```